# Volume of solid of revolution about y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I need to find the volume of a solid of revolution formed by rotating the region bounded by these curves: $y=4+x^2,$ $x=0,$ $y=4+x^2,$ and $x=1$ **about the y-axis**

Here is the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x7fxnkwuex

This is what I've got so far(using shell method): $$V=\pi\big(\int_0^4dx + 2\int_4^5(4x+x^3)dx\big)$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Any progress to share?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Sack Exchange. We will be glad to help you, but we need to know what you have tried so far.  What do you know about the solutions of these types of problems?

Comment: I have added some more information

Comment: Can someone please explain why this is getting downvoted? I am providing information on what I have tried and I have yet to receive any input on how to improve this question further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if you set the limits of integration as the $y$ values. This would work, if you were integrating with respect to $y$. That is, if you were using the washer or disk method.

The volume of a solid of revolution rotating about the **y-axis**, given the method of cylindrical shells, is given by$$V=2\pi \int_a^bxf(x) dx$$

We are integrating with respect to $x$, so our bounds are from $x=0$ to $x=1$. Plugging in for the equation, we get $$V=2\pi \int_0^1 x(4+x^2)dx = 2\pi \int_0^1(4x+x^3)dx$$
Integrating, we get
$$V=2\pi \left[2x^2+\frac 14 x^4\right]_0^1=\frac{9\pi} {2}$$

Comment: This helped a lot, thank you.